# Calculation of marginal effects mlogit, Error "Arguments mus have the same length"

Tags: r, mlogit, marginal-effects

I try to calculate the marginal effects after I conducted a multinomial logistic regression using `mlogit`.

```
reg1 <- mlogit::mlogit(formula = value ~ 1 | ScoreEnvAtt, data = listDatasets[[2]])
reg1
summary(reg1)

z <- with(listDatasets[[2]], data.frame(ScoreEnvAtt = tapply(ScoreEnvAtt, index(reg1)$alt, mean)))

effects(reg1,covariate="ScoreEnvAtt",data=z)
```

But I get an error when defining the `z`.

```
    z <- with(listDatasets[[2]], data.frame(ScoreEnvAtt = tapply(ScoreEnvAtt, index(reg1)$alt, mean)))
Error in tapply(ScoreEnvAtt, index(reg1)$alt, mean) : 
  Argumente müssen die selbe Länge haben
```

(Arguments must have the same length). And I just can't solve it. Anyone has an idea?

```
head(listDatasets[[2]])
                 index Age ScoreEnvAtt MoneyInvested Gender Beliefs_eff_Green Beliefs_eff_ESG Beliefs_eff_Comp Beliefs_perf_ESG Beliefs_perf_Green Beliefs_perf_Comp Guilt Social.Altruistic Biospheric Egoistic DummyMedium
    1.SS_Green_1     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
    1.SS_Green_2     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
    1.SS_Green_3     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
    1.SS_Green_4     1  26         4.2            13      2                 4               3                3                2                  3                 2    71          6.000000   6.000000        5           1
    2.SS_Green_1     2  30         4.8             2      2                 4               3                4                2                  3                 3    26          6.666667   5.333333        5           1
    2.SS_Green_2     2  30         4.8             2      2                 4               3                4                2                  3                 3    26          6.666667   5.333333        5           1
                 DummyHigh CompensationGroup Past_compensation Knowledge_CO2   variable value price
    1.SS_Green_1         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_1 FALSE   1.5
    1.SS_Green_2         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_2 FALSE   1.5
    1.SS_Green_3         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_3 FALSE   1.5
    1.SS_Green_4         0            Group1                 2             1 SS_Green_4  TRUE   1.3
    2.SS_Green_1         0            Group2                 2             2 SS_Green_1 FALSE   1.5
    2.SS_Green_2         0            Group2                 2             2 SS_Green_2 FALSE   1.5
```

Edit:

```
> dput(head(listDatasets[[2]]))
structure(list(index = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1, `1.SS_Green_2` = 1, 
`1.SS_Green_3` = 1, `1.SS_Green_4` = 1, `2.SS_Green_1` = 2, `2.SS_Green_2` = 2
), Age = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 26, `1.SS_Green_2` = 26, `1.SS_Green_3` = 26, 
`1.SS_Green_4` = 26, `2.SS_Green_1` = 30, `2.SS_Green_2` = 30
), ScoreEnvAtt = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 4.2, `1.SS_Green_2` = 4.2, 
`1.SS_Green_3` = 4.2, `1.SS_Green_4` = 4.2, `2.SS_Green_1` = 4.8, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 4.8), MoneyInvested = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 13, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 13, `1.SS_Green_3` = 13, `1.SS_Green_4` = 13, 
`2.SS_Green_1` = 2, `2.SS_Green_2` = 2), Gender = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 2, `1.SS_Green_3` = 2, `1.SS_Green_4` = 2, `2.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 2), Beliefs_eff_Green = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 4, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 4, `1.SS_Green_3` = 4, `1.SS_Green_4` = 4, `2.SS_Green_1` = 4, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 4), Beliefs_eff_ESG = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 3, `1.SS_Green_3` = 3, `1.SS_Green_4` = 3, `2.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 3), Beliefs_eff_Comp = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 3, `1.SS_Green_3` = 3, `1.SS_Green_4` = 3, `2.SS_Green_1` = 4, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 4), Beliefs_perf_ESG = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 2, `1.SS_Green_3` = 2, `1.SS_Green_4` = 2, `2.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 2), Beliefs_perf_Green = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 3, `1.SS_Green_3` = 3, `1.SS_Green_4` = 3, `2.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 3), Beliefs_perf_Comp = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 2, `1.SS_Green_3` = 2, `1.SS_Green_4` = 2, `2.SS_Green_1` = 3, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 3), Guilt = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 71, `1.SS_Green_2` = 71, 
`1.SS_Green_3` = 71, `1.SS_Green_4` = 71, `2.SS_Green_1` = 26, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 26), Social.Altruistic = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 6, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 6, `1.SS_Green_3` = 6, `1.SS_Green_4` = 6, `2.SS_Green_1` = 6.66666666666667, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 6.66666666666667), Biospheric = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 6, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 6, `1.SS_Green_3` = 6, `1.SS_Green_4` = 6, `2.SS_Green_1` = 5.33333333333333, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 5.33333333333333), Egoistic = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 5, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 5, `1.SS_Green_3` = 5, `1.SS_Green_4` = 5, `2.SS_Green_1` = 5, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 5), DummyMedium = structure(c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 2L, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 2L, `1.SS_Green_3` = 2L, `1.SS_Green_4` = 2L, 
`2.SS_Green_1` = 2L, `2.SS_Green_2` = 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"
), class = c("pseries", "factor")), DummyHigh = structure(c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1L, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 1L, `1.SS_Green_3` = 1L, `1.SS_Green_4` = 1L, 
`2.SS_Green_1` = 1L, `2.SS_Green_2` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"
), class = c("pseries", "factor")), CompensationGroup = structure(c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1L, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 1L, `1.SS_Green_3` = 1L, `1.SS_Green_4` = 1L, 
`2.SS_Green_1` = 2L, `2.SS_Green_2` = 2L), .Label = c("Group1", 
"Group2", "Group3"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), Past_compensation = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`1.SS_Green_2` = 2, `1.SS_Green_3` = 2, `1.SS_Green_4` = 2, `2.SS_Green_1` = 2, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 2), Knowledge_CO2 = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1, `1.SS_Green_2` = 1, 
`1.SS_Green_3` = 1, `1.SS_Green_4` = 1, `2.SS_Green_1` = 2, `2.SS_Green_2` = 2
), variable = structure(c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1L, `1.SS_Green_2` = 2L, 
`1.SS_Green_3` = 3L, `1.SS_Green_4` = 4L, `2.SS_Green_1` = 1L, 
`2.SS_Green_2` = 2L), .Label = c("SS_Green_1", "SS_Green_2", 
"SS_Green_3", "SS_Green_4"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), 
    value = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = FALSE, `1.SS_Green_2` = FALSE, 
    `1.SS_Green_3` = FALSE, `1.SS_Green_4` = TRUE, `2.SS_Green_1` = FALSE, 
    `2.SS_Green_2` = FALSE), price = c(`1.SS_Green_1` = 1.5, 
    `1.SS_Green_2` = 1.5, `1.SS_Green_3` = 1.5, `1.SS_Green_4` = 1.3, 
    `2.SS_Green_1` = 1.5, `2.SS_Green_2` = 1.5)), index = structure(list(
    chid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), alt = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("SS_Green_1", "SS_Green_2", "SS_Green_3", 
    "SS_Green_4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.SS_Green_1", 
"1.SS_Green_2", "1.SS_Green_3", "1.SS_Green_4", "2.SS_Green_1", 
"2.SS_Green_2")), choice = "value", row.names = c("1.SS_Green_1", 
"1.SS_Green_2", "1.SS_Green_3", "1.SS_Green_4", "2.SS_Green_1", 
"2.SS_Green_2"), class = c("mlogit.data", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share the output of the command `dput(head(listDatasets[[2]]))`?

Comment: Well, the reason obviously is that `ScoreEnvAtt` and `index(reg1)$alt` have different lengths. That is something you can check easily. If they have different lengths, you first need to consider why you expect them to have the same length. (I'm not that familiar with `mlogit` but a frequent gotcha is handling of missing values).

Comment: @John I added the output to the original post!

Comment: @Roland So far I did not quite understand the command `index(reg1)$alt`, which is why I can not say anything about its lenght.

Comment: Of course you can: `length(index(reg1)$alt)`. Why are you using commands that you don't understand?

Comment: I slightly modified the data shared to get the model to run - it worked fine. I agree with Roland - it is probably something wrong with index(reg1)$alt. I get an object with same length as number of rows in dataframe. Check to make sure the index function is masked by another package by using `mlogit::index(reg1)$alt` (index sounds like a very common function name to me)